# Notifying two pojo fields with same name Data Binding

Tags: android, android-databinding

I started using the data binding library 2 months ago and really like it. But I'm running into an issue. I have for example the following POJO's:

```
Car{
    @Bindable
    var name: String
    @Bindable
    set(value){
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)
    }
}

Bike{
    @Bindable
    var name: String
    @Bindable
    set(value){
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)
    }
}
```

So basically I have a Car and Bike POJO that share a property name. They both have a name. The problem is that the BR class will only have one of them, it does not generate a prefix for the class. I tested this and the notifyPropertyChanged method for one of them will not work.
This is really annoying. Now I have to put a prefix on  both or one of them so they don't match. This solves the problem but then the Bike class becomes:

```
Bike{
    @Bindable
    var bikeName: String
    @Bindable
    set(value){
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.bikeName)
    }
}
```

This works but I of course do not want to implement my models like this. Anyone that knows how to solve this?

Comment: Does your UI not update when you call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)`

Comment: The UI only updates for one of them, this is basically the model that had the property first. For the second model the UI won't update.

Comment: UI will be updated of the pojo in which you are calling `notifyPropertyChanged`, this method relates to BaseObservable class, so related pojo will be refreshed. Why you want to update both pojo at single time?

Comment: I don't want to update both pojo's at the same time. What I'm sayins is when you have to completely unrelated pojo's but they use the same name for a property, only one of them will get notified for changes. This is due to a single ID being generated in the BR class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Kotlin Inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html). You have common fields for both classes.

```
open class Vehicle : BaseObservable() {
    @Bindable
    var name: String = ""
        @Bindable
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)
        }
}

class Bike : Vehicle() {

}

class Car : Vehicle() {

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but getting the same problem. The notifyPropertyChanged 
 of BaseObservable method checks for callbacks, and those are null.